# Adding data validation/macro to existing xls file using python on linux

Tags: python, linux, excel, vba

I have a bunch of xls files to which i need to add a data validation (comboboxes) for some cells using python. I am working on linux.

Alternatively, the same could be achieved by adding a macro to a Worksheet that will run upon the file opening and insert data validation.

Most libraries I found were either for Windows or were not able to do that/edit existing file.

Any ideas what is the best (or at least possible) way to achieve that?